# two verbs with two objects

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, objects

Does the following sound like natural English?

> The mayor **acknowledged** and **received** **the protest**, along with **a** **petition** with 40 signatures.

A coworker of mine, who is a native speaker of English, wrote it. The only way to make sense of it would be to associate each of the two verbs with one of the two objects separately, so that **acknowledged** takes **the protest** as is object and **received** takes **a petition** as its object. But this does not seem to be how a two-verb sequence is interpreted.

Comment: It's fine, but it might not mean what you think it means.  As written, both verbs apply to both objects, which is somewhat confusing since you can't really *receive* a *protest*.  You can receive *protesters*, however.

Comment: What does it mean to acknowledge a protest?

Comment: This seems like borderline proofreading. I know you’re trying to focus on the “two verbs and two objects” aspect, but  you should at least tell us where you got this sentence and tell us what you think it means.

Comment: @Apollyon  It would mean something like "to recognize that the protest is for legitimate reasons".  For example, in the Unites States many (including the President) choose not to **acknowledge** the protest made by NFL [players who kneel during the national anthem.](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/taking-a-knee-national-anthem-nfl-trump-why-meaning-origins-racism-us-colin-kaepernick-a7966961.html).

Answer (score 1):

The object of **received** is not required to be a physical object that you take into your hands.

On a semantic level, the **protest** refers to *protesters-doing-something*, and so because it has this human element, a protest can be **received** as guests may be received, or as news or some bit of information may be received.

> The mayor received the protest graciously because he was an ardent
>   supporter of free speech and the right of the people to make their grievances known.

Since a protest is an attempt to make grievances known, it can also be **acknowledged**, that is, the mayor can express understanding of the purpose of the protest, that the issues the protesters wish to make known have been made known.